# How can you use an old router for streaming without internet

Tags: networking

I would like to know if you turn and ol Archer D20 adsl router into a portable wireless hotspot (portable wifi network) so that I can use it to stream movies from a storage device and and or use a priivate wireless network.

I read somewhere on here that you can connect it to itself from modem port to one of the land ports but am new to wireless networking so would like a guide on how to do this if any are avaliable. does not have to have internet access but if it came accross a wifi source would bridge to it. can this be done

Or is turning it into a hotspot or virtual server/network the way to go.

Comment: Generally with an ADSL or Cable modem/router combo units, this isn't possible as much of the router functionality is hard-coded into the routing. With stand-alone Wireless Router's it is usually pretty simple, but not in the AIO units.